# Restrict firefox extensions or only activate them manually for certain tabs for more privacy protection

Tags: firefox, security, firefox-extensions, privacy

Some firefox extensions require quite intrusive permissions, which can be understandable depending on what the extension does, but would not be necessary to be granted all the time. **Is there a simple or more direct approach to restrict such extensions in firefox?**

What I have tried so far / know of:

- Mozilla's curation program for extensions: A third party verifiying what an extension does with its permissions is helpful for making a more informed tradeoff between permission and functionality. Sadly, many, also highly used, extensions haven't been curated yet.
- I've read about click-to-script and extension restriction options of chrome 70 upwards in the mozilla add-ons blog (https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2018/10/26/firefox-chrome-and-the-future-of-trustworthy-extensions/), but wasn't able to find anything new regarding it. A comment guiding me to a newer resource of the topic or even synonyms of the click-to-script functionality I haven't found would definitely help me solve this problem myself. The best case would be if this functionality was already implemented and I'm simply unaware of it, but I doubt that because of the lack of information I came across.
- My current practice is to disable most of the (not-curated) extensions that require permissions like "accessing the data of any website" and only activating them when I need them. Kind of like a manual click-to-script. This, however, is quite tedious, and to be completely safe, I also need to close all other tabs except the one I want the functionality in, everytime I need it.

I don't simply switch to chrome because I prefer firefox's open-source nature and general privacy practices. The kind of black-and-white nature of either trusting an extension all the time or not using it is the only thorn in my side.

To make an example: When using an extension that was granted "access to all website data", this extension has the means to read your passwords, payment info, adresses, et cetera all the time, everywhere. For an e.g. translator, reading the website is of course necessary, but the functionality is only required when you'd want to translate a website, not all the time.

Comment: You can create multiple Firefox profiles with different plugins installed and then use them [at the same time](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/firefox/use-multiple-firefox-profiles-at-the-same-time/). Or use the private mode as most plugins are not active in this mode.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for pointing me to that, hadn't known of it! After some trials, using profiles solves the problem of having to close unrelated tabs before activating a concerning extension. Still, it's not quite as simple as it could be from what I think, like it would be with click-to-script, which only needs a click and no set up for every extension. Also, firefox sync can't be used to sync extensions and settings anymore, so the profiles need to be kept in sync by other means. Would it be customary here to leave the question open a bit longer and see whether another option arises?

Answer (score 1):

There is some work in progress to restrict extensions access with Firefox:

- https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/disable-add-ons-on-specific-website/33693
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1497075
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1711787

It will probably mimic some already existing approaches in other browsers like Safari.

In the meanwhile, as *Robert* says, there is also the possibility to create different profiles within Firefox, with different extensions enabled in each of those.